# GIT Hook - Shared hosting and Laravel

Tags: git, laravel-5, shared-hosting, githooks

I avec a Laravel 5 project, my git repository on the server is in `projects/projectA/.git` and this is where I push my developments.

Since I am on a shared hosting server I would like to synchronize the `public` folder of my project with the `public_html`.

I was about to create a `post-receive` hook, but I don't know exactly how to do that.

Otherwise is there another solution so I don't have to manually copy paste the `public` folder to `public_html` after a new push ?

## Structure of ~ folder

```
projects/
    projectA/
        .git/
        public/
        ....
public_html/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was about to create a post-receive hook

You add an executable file name `post-receive` (a [server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks)) in the .git/hooks folder of your destination repo with a [`rsync` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) (since you are pushing to a non-bare repo):

```
rsync projects/projectA/public public_html
```

Comment: Is this command doing in way of  some kind "redirecitng" public folder to public_html?

Comment: @Dejan It does not "redirect", but copy one folder content to another: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync